# Lambda function for list of values in Parameters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Im using below python code to create stack in AWS
would like to send values as list/array for one of the parameter but im getting error as below:

```
import boto3
import time

date = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
time = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
stackname = 'FulfillSNSELB'
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
response = client.create_stack(
    StackName= (stackname + '-' + date + '-' + time),
    TemplateURL='https://s3.amazonaws.com/****/**/myapp.json',
    Parameters=[
        {
            'ParameterKey': 'Subnets',
            'ParameterValue': 'subnet-1,subnet-2',
            'Type':'CommaDelimitedList',
            'UsePreviousValue': False
        }]
)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return(response)
```

---

```
module initialization error: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in Parameters[15]: "Type", must be one of: ParameterKey, ParameterValue, UsePreviousValue
```

Comment: Please format this correctly if you would. This wouldn't run.

Comment: @Goodies I assume I got the formatting fixed...

Comment: @shiv455 Umm... "ParameterKey, ParameterValue, UsePreviousValue". You have one called "Type".

Comment: yeah @Goodies, I think they're trying to do something similar highlighted here; http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html; whether or not its possible in this case...

Comment: @Goodies yeah i know "Type" is incorrect..but the intention is to provide the value as list/array instead of string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly observed, `Type` cannot be specified as a parameter in `create_stack()`.

Instead you should specify the type in the template `TemplateURL='https://s3.amazonaws.com/****/**/myapp.json'` so that the comma delimited value `'ParameterValue': 'subnet-1,subnet-2'` is accepted.

Example template that accepts CommaDelimitedList as a parameter.

```
"Parameters" : {
  "DbSubnetIpBlocks": {
    "Description": "Comma-delimited list of three CIDR blocks",
    "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
    "Default": "10.0.48.0/24, 10.0.112.0/24, 10.0.176.0/24"
  }
}
```

In your case, the stack should be like this:

```
"Parameters" : {
  "Subnets": {
    "Description": "Comma-delimited list of CIDR blocks",
    "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
    "Default": "10.0.48.0/24"
  }
}
```

Now you can create your stack, without specifying `Type`

Comment: i have specified the accepted value as [] instead of '' inside the template .i mean array instead of string...is it fine if give accepted value as string ideally it should be array for subnets ,securitygroups rt..?correct me if im wrong

Comment: No, Type can be specified only in the template, you cannot specify it when creating the stack. See the example I have provided.

Comment: yeah that makes sense!!

Comment: it fails if im passing the list to child inside nested stack... "Value of property Parameters must be an object with String (or simple type) properties"

Comment: the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html    says "If you use the ref function to pass a parameter value to a nested stack, comma-delimited list parameters must be of type String. In other words, you cannot pass values that are of type CommaDelimitedList to nested stacks."